# How to build RESTful Webservice API for PhoneGap application using Django and Mongodb?

Tags: django, tastypie, mongoengine

I want to build a RESTful webservice api handle phonegap application request.
I am familiar with Python and Django.

Restful webservice is a social network like Twitter, required to use Mongodb. Everyone can post status photo from mobile app to server and can follow anyone. I have read about django-tastypie to build restful api but I want to use mongodb. About mongodb driver for django I have read mongoengein.

What about commbo django + django-tastypie + mongoengien? Is is suitable for me?

Answer (score 1):

There is this https://github.com/mitar/django-tastypie-mongoengine .  Weather the tastypie model is the right choice depends on many factors, but it's ability to create a standards compliant REST that works with backbone.js will continue to encourage use.  It's pretty nice to extend as well - taking alot of inspiration from the way you define ModelAdmins in django.  Not having to come up with your own authentication system or integrate oauth by hand is appealing (but sometimes an existing authentication is required if you are building this into an old application).

I have tried to implement basic API endpoints with plain mongoengine and ran into many serialization issues (ObjectIDs and many other fields) and inability to get relations or easily or control the inclusion and detail of embedded documents, so it is worth at least putting some time into evaluation and tinkering with Tastypie.  Like the mongoengine django admin - you wont find 100% seamless recreation of the SQL version but rolling your own solution here is a high level of effort.